# JDBC while(!rs.next()) is stuck in a loop

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Trying to make a login with sql that lets the user re-enter the username and password if one of them doesnt match what is in the database. The problem is that when the username and password does match, it keeps asking the user for the information again instead of stopping the loop. I am not sure, but I think the culprit might be the while(!rs.next());

```
public void loginAccount(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        String login;
        ResultSet rs;

        do {
            System.out.print("Enter Username: ");
            Username = in.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter Password: ");
            Password = in.nextLine();

            login = "SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Username = ? AND AccPassword = ?";
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(login);

            ps.setString(1, Username);
            ps.setString(2, Password);

            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            if (!rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect Username or Password");
            }
        }   while (!rs.next());

    }
```

Comment: Your hunch is correct. The second call to `next()` will return false if there's only 1 result. If you want to check the first result again, store it in a variable.

Answer (score 2):

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70688525/jdbc-whilers-next-is-stuck-in-a-loop#comment124965259_70688525), your second call is returning `false`.

Be aware that this behavior is up to the implementation of the [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver). A second call to `next` (after the first returned `false`) *might* return `false` *or* might throw an exception.

To quote the Javadoc:

> If the result set type is `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`, it is vendor specified whether their JDBC driver implementation will return `false` or throw an `SQLException` on a subsequent call to next.

You need to change your code to call `rs.next()` only once per intended row access.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no result set rs.next gives false but your using not operation making the while loop condition true.

try changinf while(!rs.next()) to while(rs.next)